# Using Identity Pool (AWS Cognito) Choose Role From Token and using the IdToken inside lambda for Dynamo Access

Tags: lambda, amazon-cognito

So I am authenticating against the Cognito User Pool. Back-end Lambda needs to have the temporary secretKey and accessKey so that it can authorise the requester to Dynamo.
The requester or the user is in a group in Cognito User Pool which has FullDynamoDBAccess.

And I have chosen Choose Role From Token in Authenticated Role Section in identity Pool.

But while I am trying to get the temp access details,it throws "Missing credentials in config" error ["InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException"]. 
If I change the Choose Role from token to default, the error disappears.

```
        AWS.config.region = "****";
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: "*****",
            IdentityId: "****",
            Logins: {
                "***": event.id_token
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and fixed it with a change to the trust policy for the role assigned to the Cognito User Pool group.  The trust policy must name the Identity pool.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is the Logins: { '***': token }

the *** must be invalid... you need to use something like:
'cognito-idp..amazonaws.com/'